# how can i input a validation PHP

Tags: php

Good day!

How can I produce an error if i input a letter instead of number because characters can still be encoded.... My code is as follows:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

Please enter your grade (0-100 only):
<FORM ACTION="grade.php" METHOD="POST">
<table border = "1">
    <tr>
        <td>Grade</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="grade" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="grade status">
</FORM>
<?php

$grade = $_POST['grade'];
IF ($grade>=0 && $grade<=50){
    print "You failed";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=60){
    print "You Passed! But Study Harder!";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=70){
    print "Nice";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=80) {
    print "Great Job";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=90){
    print "Excellent";
} ELSE IF ($grade<=100){
    print "God Like!";
} ELSE {
    print "Invalid Grade!";
}   
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: If you're using HTML5 you can do this with a number input type http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/ , but make sure to always validate on the client-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the input text's ascii to see if it is number or not!

or use `is_numeric($var);`

Comment: use echo not print, coz it's slightly faster as prints returns 0/1

Comment: @newbie just know that `is_numeric()` will return `true` for things that are not `0-9` ;; for example, `is_numeric('-1.5e5')` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

To check if something only contains digits, see the [**`ctype_digit()`**](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit) function.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function isInteger(s)
{   var i=document.s.grad.value;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
        // Check that current character is number.
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (((c < "0") || (c > "9"))) 
            {
alert("Must Enter Number");
            return false;
            }
    }
    // All characters are numbers.
    return true;
}

</script>
```

and call this function in form tab

```
<FORM ACTION="grade.php" METHOD="POST" onSubmint="isInteger(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $str)) {

} else {

}
```